Accuracy of $\int_{0}^{1}\sin^2(x)dx$ using MacLaurin series
Since
$$\sin^2(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\cdot\frac{2^{2n-1}\cdot x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$
I evaluated
$$\int_{0}^{1}\sin^2(x)dx$$
using the first four terms of the series as follows
$$\int_{0}^{1}\sin^2(x)dx=\int_{0}^{1}\left(x^2-\frac{x^{4}}{3}+\frac{2x^6}{45}-\frac{x^8}{315}\right)dx=\frac{2903}{11340}$$
However, the exercise asks to indicate the accuracy I found and I don't know how to do it. Should I evaluate the integral as
$$\int_{0}^{1}\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\cos(2x)}{2}\right)dx?$$
And if so, how do I find the accuracy?

@Moo to be honest, I don't think so because they give an error to estimate, while my exercise does not.

@Moo so, I do have to evaluate the exact result to conclude? And no, I don't know how to calculate the accuracy.

@Moo it doens't mention which one should I use. All it asks is "indicate the accurracy you found".

This particular integral has an elementary antiderivative, so you can calculate the exact value.
$$\int_{0}^{1}\sin^2(x)dx$$
$$= \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1 - \cos(2x)}{2} dx$$
$$= \frac{1}{2} [x - \frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)]_{x=0}^{x=1}$$
$$= \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4}\sin(2)$$
$$\approx 0.2726756432935796$$
The MacLaurin series approximation you found is (to IEEE double-precision) $0.25599647266313935$.
The error is simply the difference between those two numbers, or approximately $0.016679$.

For an analytic function $f(x)$ in an interval $(a-r,a+r)$ for $r>0$, it is possible to interchange integral and summation as follows
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(x-a)^n
\implies
\int_{a-r}^{a+r}f(x)dx=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\int_{a-r}^{a+r}(x-a)^ndx
=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\frac{r^{n+1}-(-r)^{n+1}}{n+1},
$$
assuming that $\int_{a-r}^{a+r}f(x)dx$ exists. The error of approximating the integral up to the first $N$ terms of series is
$$
E_N=\left|\sum_{n=N}^\infty a_n\frac{r^{n+1}-(-r)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right|.
$$
Finding an exact expression for $E_N$ is typically hard. Sometimes, a tight enough bound helps. In your case, an error bound can be given by
$$
E_{10}
{=
\left|\sum_{n=5}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\cdot\frac{2^{2n-1}}{(2n+1)!}\right|
\\=
\left|\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}(-1)^{2n}\cdot\frac{2^{4n-3}}{(4n-1)!}
+
(-1)^{2n+1}\cdot\frac{2^{4n-1}}{(4n+1)!}
\right|
\\=
\left|\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2^{4n-3}}{(4n-1)!}
-
\frac{2^{4n-1}}{(4n+1)!}
\right|
\\=
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{2^{4n-3}}{(4n-1)!}\frac{4n^2+n-1}{4n^2+n}\approx 0.8\%.
}
$$
